# Android devices connected to USB on Ubuntu will not load

Tags: android-studio, usb

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, and 
I am trying to create Android apply using Android-studio.
For that purpose, we are going to connect the Android machine to the PC and debug it.

I connected the Android machine to the PC using USB, but the Android machine was not loaded.

At first it thought that it was caused by not adding a rule to `udev`.
Fortunately, since my Android machine was HTC, we added a rule to`udev` with reference to the official documentation.
However, it was still not loaded.

I checked `lsusb`, but the Android machine information such as the `vendor ID` was not loaded.
The following is the execution result of `lsusb`.

```sh
 $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:b002 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 056e:00e3 Elecom Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

From the developer mode on Android real machine, USB debugging is enabled, USB configuration is MTP.

**I think that the cable is the cause of such a problem.**
However, trying with multiple USB cables did not solve the problem.
Therefore, I think that there is a cause in Ubuntu's system.

I would like to inform you that you can identify the cause of this problem in more detail and need to investigate further.

## Solution

This problem is solved.
The reason was that I was using USB-C cable.
I used a cable for charging.
I could connect successfully when I bought a new cable.
Below is the URL in amazon.
https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B0791FBQ83/ref=cm_sw_r_tw_dp_U_x_X5IHCb2V1KVZB
Thank you for answering.

Comment: no issue found but I suggest  you to try once to connect via wifi -Debug Your Android App over WiFi -https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-debug-your-android-app-over-wifi-without-root

Answer (score 1):

Please check your ADB driver if you not install, first install it.

https://www.howtogeek.com/125769/how-to-install-and-use-abd-the-android-debug-bridge-utility/

And if that does not work, you can try running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you're using root and run this commands on your terminal

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

check if daemon was successfully then write this:

```
adb devices
```

It should show list of device attached to your system.